# Using sklearn's LogisticRegression with 'saga' solver and 'elasticnet' penalty

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I was using LogisticRegression from sklearn with 'liblinear' solver and the default penalty (l2). And the code was working fine:

```
LR = LogisticRegression(random_state=1, solver='liblinear')
LR.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train)
x_test_scaled = min_max_scaler.transform(x_test)
y_pred = LR.predict(x_test_scaled)
```

I tried l1 (LASSO) with 'liblinear' since I have a lot of correlated features in my predictors and I wanted to reduce their coefficients to zero. The code ran fine, but the LR performance did not improve. So, now I want to try elastic net to see its effect on the model (have to use 'saga' solver with elastic net). But now my code throws an error that I don't know how to resolve?

Code:

```
LR = LogisticRegression(random_state=1, solver='saga', penalty='elasticnet')
LR.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train)
x_test_scaled = min_max_scaler.transform(x_test)
y_pred = LR.predict(x_test_scaled)
```

error on the second line (fitting step):

```
ValueError: l1_ratio must be between 0 and 1; got (l1_ratio=None)
```

Comment: `l1_ratio` is None by default because `penalty=l2` by default (and l2 regularization induces `l1_ratio=0`). With elastic net, you should specify 0<`l1_ratio`<1. I would suggest to have a look at the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
diabetic_classifer = LogisticRegression(penalty='elasticnet',solver='saga',C=0.5,l1_ratio=1)
diabetic_classifer.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I guess you have to set `l1_ratio=1`, it's one of the parameters. I also don't fully understand it. I believe we can set it between 0 and 1.

Would like more info.

Comment: Setting a value of 0 is equivalent to 'l2', while 1 is equivalent to 'l1', so you'd typically want a value strictly between 0 and 1. Note that the argument must be a list, so e.g. set `l1_ratios=[0.5]`. (tested June 2022) See the manual: "A value of 0 is equivalent to using penalty='l2', while 1 is equivalent to using penalty='l1'. For 0 < l1_ratio <1, the penalty is a combination of L1 and L2."